# Does the Spider Control Rod work on spiders other than Aicantar's Spider?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In Calcelmo's Laboratory in Markarth, there is a Spider Control Rod that controls a specific dwarven spider called "Aicantar's Spider." Does it work on other dwarven spiders?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It only works on Aicantar's Spider.

Other spiders won't even care.

According to the wiki:

http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Spider_Control_Rod

The Spider Control Rod shoots a beam of energy which Aicantar's Spider walks towards. As the spider cannot be interacted with aside from the use of the Spider Control Rod, it does not seem possible for the spider to move outside of the laboratory area. The only other use is during the quest "Hard Answers," using the spider as a way to sneak past the hallway filled with poisonous gas. The rod has no apparent function beyond this.

With the release of Dawnguard, the Dragonborn can attain the Aetherial Staff, which will allow a Dwarven Spider or Dwarven Sphere to be summoned for 60 seconds.

Comment: you don't have to quote the wikia to me... I always research on there before I ask a question on here.  But thanks!

Comment: @Horus If you did some research, you should include that in your question. That can help with upvotes, and will let the answerer know. Otherwise, it's perfectly reasonable to assume that you didn't look at the wiki, especially since that's where the answerer got the answer.

Comment: But if it did work you would have a spider army in the dwarven ruins.  Its funny because I kept trying to make the damn spider to go outside the laboratory and it wouldn't.  Maybe someone should mod that.